# Unable to make write only smb share

Tags: raspbian, samba, share

I have the home folder of my Raspberry Pi B+ shared via SMB working fine. Now i'm trying to make a public, write only folder: i edited the configuration like so but it doesn't seem to work. I can't write anything to that folder.

Configuration:

```
[public]
path = /home/pi/Kingston/Public
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
browsable = no
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your directory mask to 0766 => 6 = read and write

5 = read and execute

Edit: the directory mask is equivalent to the unix file system permissions in numeric notation. Therefore 0 means no permissions, 1 means execute and so on.

Further reading here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation

Edit 2: Like goldilocks corrected me a directory needs also execution permission. Therefore the mask has to be **0777**. Like Chris Down explained in his [answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/123642):

> The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside

Comment: you might explain how and why 6 = read and write etc.

Comment: I know about permissions but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: **Because directories require executable access**.  That should be 0777, not 0766.  If you want to make something equally accessible by everyone, then the last three numbers of the mask should be the same.  To explain: 4 is read, 2 is write, 1 is execute (see that wikipedia article).

Comment: I still can't get it to work, i have set both create make and directory mask to 0777 and also set the permissions of Public to 777.

Comment: Try set `read only = no`.

Comment: Found the issue: Public is in the home folder which in my case has permission 750 so other users can't read, write child folders

Comment: @Matteo If you solve your problem, it oculd be nice to share it answering instead of commenting.

Comment: You should probably set `/home` 755 in this case then.  This way anyone can read in to find a directory (e.g., one that is writable to them), but they won't be able to write to `/home` itself.

Comment: @mpromonet Didn't check if this solved, i will update the post as soon as i have time to try.